# Exception on app startup Mono for Android when Breakpoint is set

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2013

I created a sample Android app in VS 2013 using the latest Xamarin release.

The app works fine if I run it in debug mode without breakpoints but crashes on startup if I put a breakpoint in it.

The following is the debug window output

```
Loaded assembly: AndroidApplication1.dll
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
Mono.Android.VisualStudio.MonoAndroidPackage Error: 0 : MonoAndroidDebuggerSession
System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveFullPath(String path)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.PathsAreEqual(String p1, String p2)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveBreakpoints(TypeMirror type)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEvent(Event e)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet(EventSet es)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler()
01-23 20:48:34.024 E/SELinux (11998): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
01-23 20:48:34.029 D/dalvikvm(11998): Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-23 20:48:34.089 D/dalvikvm(11998): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1-1/libmonodroid.so 0x42212b38
01-23 20:48:34.089 D/dalvikvm(11998): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1-1/libmonodroid.so 0x42212b38
01-23 20:48:34.094 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(11998): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8965,server=y,embedding=1
01-23 20:48:34.264 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(11998): Accepted stdout connection: 51
01-23 20:48:35.029 W/libc    (11998): WARNING: generic atexit() called from legacy shared library
01-23 20:48:35.039 D/Mono    (11998): Image addref mscorlib[0x751e63f0] -> mscorlib.dll[0x71bce850]: 1
01-23 20:48:35.044 D/Mono    (11998): AOT failed to load AOT module mscorlib.dll.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1/lib/mscorlib.dll.so" not found
01-23 20:48:35.114 D/Mono    (11998): GC_MAJOR: (mature allocation failure) pause 1.17ms, total 1.17ms, bridge 0.02ms major 112K/32K los 0K/0K
01-23 20:48:35.124 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly mscorlib[0x751e63f0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
01-23 20:48:37.149 D/Mono    (11998): Image addref AndroidApplication1[0x753db9f0] -> AndroidApplication1.dll[0x753db008]: 1
01-23 20:48:37.149 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly AndroidApplication1[0x753db9f0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
01-23 20:48:37.149 D/Mono    (11998): AOT failed to load AOT module AndroidApplication1.dll.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1/lib/AndroidApplication1.dll.so" not found
01-23 20:48:37.149 W/monodroid-gc(11998): GREF GC Threshold: 46800
01-23 20:48:37.154 D/Mono    (11998): Image addref Mono.Android[0x753e0cd0] -> Mono.Android.dll[0x753e02d8]: 1
01-23 20:48:37.154 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly Mono.Android[0x753e0cd0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
01-23 20:48:37.159 D/Mono    (11998): AOT failed to load AOT module Mono.Android.dll.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1/lib/Mono.Android.dll.so" not found
01-23 20:48:37.234 W/Mono    (11998): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
01-23 20:48:37.234 D/Mono    (11998): Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0x753face0].
01-23 20:48:37.234 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x753e0cd0] -> mscorlib[0x751e63f0]: 2
01-23 20:48:37.404 W/Mono    (11998): The request to load the assembly System.Core v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v3.5.0.0
01-23 20:48:37.404 D/Mono    (11998): Image addref System.Core[0x791a6e58] -> System.Core.dll[0x791a1e00]: 1
01-23 20:48:37.404 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly System.Core[0x791a6e58] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
01-23 20:48:37.404 D/Mono    (11998): AOT failed to load AOT module System.Core.dll.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1/lib/System.Core.dll.so" not found
01-23 20:48:37.404 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x753e0cd0] -> System.Core[0x791a6e58]: 2
01-23 20:48:37.404 W/Mono    (11998): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
01-23 20:48:37.404 D/Mono    (11998): Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0x7938fe20].
01-23 20:48:37.404 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly Ref addref System.Core[0x791a6e58] -> mscorlib[0x751e63f0]: 3
01-23 20:48:37.489 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly Ref addref AndroidApplication1[0x753db9f0] -> Mono.Android[0x753e0cd0]: 2
01-23 20:48:38.124 D/Mono    (11998): DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
01-23 20:48:38.124 D/Mono    (11998): DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
01-23 20:48:38.124 D/Mono    (11998): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
01-23 20:48:38.124 D/Mono    (11998): Searching for '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
01-23 20:48:38.124 D/Mono    (11998): Probing '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
01-23 20:48:38.124 D/Mono    (11998): Found as '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
01-23 20:48:38.544 W/Mono    (11998): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
01-23 20:48:38.549 D/Mono    (11998): Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0x796ff228].
01-23 20:48:38.549 D/Mono    (11998): Assembly Ref addref AndroidApplication1[0x753db9f0] -> mscorlib[0x751e63f0]: 4
System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveFullPath(String path)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.PathsAreEqual(String p1, String p2)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveBreakpoints(TypeMirror type)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEvent(Event e)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet(EventSet es)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler()
```

I spent all day trying to figure it out what was happening to no avail.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Alberto

Comment: Problem still exists, however starting the app debug without breakpoint and adding breakpoint while the app is running seems to be the way to go. Bug in Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was to disable fast deployment.
Right click your project -> properties -> Android Options -> unckeck 'Use Fast Deployment'

In another case I had to check 'Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI in addition to the above.